# Fetch request returns 422 error - 'value is not a valid dict'

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to send a post request to my api, however I am getting a 422 response. In insomnia, using the exact same body and everything, I am able to successfully make the request, so I am unsure why my code doesn't do the exact same.

```
    const[stopinfo, setStopInfo] = useState([]);

const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ 
        'min_date': startDate,
        'max_date': endDate,
        'min_time': '00:00:00',
        'max_time': '23:00:00',
        'bus_ids': [2,3,4],
        'route_ids': [1,2,3]
     })
};

const fetchStopData = async () => {
fetch("https://mywebsite.com/api/data/stopinfo", requestOptions).then(response => response.json())
.then(data => setStopInfo(data))
    }

useEffect(() => {
    fetchStopData()
  },[]);
```

[image: error message]
[image: insomnia]

Comment: remove quotations from your object key, or don't stringify it.

Comment: @FarbodShabani that will not accomplish anything. In fact, if you're supplying JSON, you're supposed to pass in JSON, not an object. Other valid values are Blob, or a URLSearchParames, depending on the type of request made.

Comment: What is the value of `startDate` and `endDate` in your request body?

Comment: I think `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` is missing in `requestOptions`

Comment: @VLAZ i did try adding that earlier and got an error - "Access to fetch at 'https://mywebsite/api/data/stopinfo' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status." I have my private key set up already.

Comment: Then you have a cors issue. there are thousands of questions like that on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Comment: @Evert I fixed the cors issue and still get a 422 error.

Comment: Show the headers, including the payload to the server. Your screenshot shows a js object under the JSON  tab which makes the whole question ambiguous.

Comment: @morganney i don't understand. I have updated my code to include the content type header, but I am passing that exact data in insomnia via POST and it returns back my JSON data.